# Show notifications in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

I have a string: `Công ty Thành Bưởi vừa gửi cho bạn một tin nhắn Xin chào&@http://nhomxe.vn`. Now, I use notification to send this string to my application, my application will show all this string on notification bar. But I only want to show: `Công ty Thành Bưởi vừa gửi cho bạn một tin nhắn Xin chào` on notification bar without showing `http://nhomxe.vn`. Because I want to get the link for my application and don't want to show it on the notification bar.

My code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: 
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  // Override point for customization after application launch.
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

if (launchOptions != nil) {
    // Launched from push notification
    NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    NSLog(@"Chuoi nhan duoc: %@", notification);
}
return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:

 (NSDictionary*)userInfo
 {
NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
NSDictionary *data = [ userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
for(NSString *key in data) {
    NSString *info = [data objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"thong tin nhan dc: %@ : %@", key, info);
}

NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
NSArray *info = [message componentsSeparatedByString:@"&@"];
NSString *body = [info objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *link = [info objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"Thong tin Link: %@",link);
}
```

Comment: Why are you sending the URL in message of the notification? You can just add a custom key so that you do not have to parse the string.

Comment: Send tokens in the push and add these to the Localizable.strings folder with the desired output.

Comment: thank you! i forget custom key.